# Access running container during new container docker build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How to access the running containers during new container docker build?

Need to access the database container during the build of the application container

docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    build: ./db
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  app:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork: {}
```

Tried to bring up the db prior to building the app container, but not working:

- docker-compose build db
- docker-compose up -d db
- docker-compose build app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, and it's not a good idea.  For example, if you run:

```sh
docker-compose build
docker-compose down -v
docker-compose up
```

The `down` step will delete all of the containers and their underlying storage (including the contents of the database); then the `up` step will create all new containers from existing images without re-running the Dockerfile.  Even if you added a `--build` option, Docker's layer caching would conclude that the filesystem output of your database setup command hasn't changed, and will skip re-running that step.

You can encounter a similar problem if you `docker push` the built image to some registry and run it on a different host: since the image is reusable, commands from its Dockerfile won't get re-run, but it's not the same database, so the setup won't get done.

Depending on what kind of setup you're trying to do, probably the best approach is to configure your image with an entrypoint script that runs your application's database migrations, then `exec "$@"` runs the main container command.  It can also work to put setup commands in the database's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, though these won't get re-run if your application's database schema changes.

At a technical level, this doesn't work because the `docker build` environment isn't on any particular Docker network, neither the `mynetwork` you manually specify nor the `default` network Compose creates on its own.  The build sequence runs separately from running the resulting image, and it ignores most of the Docker Compose settings.