# Error communicating with database: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: rust, docker-compose

I failed to build my Rust API in docker due to this error below.

I reckon that it could be due to the PostgreSQL connection issue.

```
#0 131.9 error: error communicating with database: Cannot assign requested address (os error 99)
#0 131.9   --> src/persistance/answers_dao.rs:33:22
#0 131.9    |
#0 131.9 33 |           let record = sqlx::query!(
#0 131.9    |  ______________________^
#0 131.9 34 | |             r#"
#0 131.9 35 | |                 INSERT INTO answers ( question_uuid, content )
#0 131.9 36 | |                 VALUES ( $1, $2 )
#0 131.9 ...  |
#0 131.9 40 | |             answer.content
#0 131.9 41 | |         )
#0 131.9    | |_________^
#0 131.9    |
#0 131.9    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::sqlx_macros::expand_query` which comes from the expansion of the macro `sqlx::query` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
#0 131.9 
#0 131.9 error: error communicating with database: Cannot assign requested address (os error 99)
#0 131.9   --> src/persistance/answers_dao.rs:75:23
#0 131.9    |
#0 131.9 75 |         let records = sqlx::query!("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_uuid = $1", question_uuid)
#0 131.9    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 131.9    |
#0 131.9    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::sqlx_macros::expand_query` which comes from the expansion of the macro `sqlx::query` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
#0 131.9 
#0 132.1 error: could not compile `rest_api` due to 2 previous errors
```

I have configured a PG db and with the proper connection string. Here is my `docker-compose` file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:

  postgresdb:
      container_name: postgresdb
      image: "postgres:13.3"
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234
        - POSTGRES_DB=rustdb
      volumes:
        - rust_api_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  rust_backend:
    container_name: rust_backend
    image: rust-api:1.0.0
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:1234@postgresdb:5432/rustdb?sslmode=disable
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
  
  

volumes:
  rust_api_data: {}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ***DISCLAIMER***: it's a workaround, not the answer for the initial question

I had the same issue, I went for another solution

### The workaround

> **TL;DR**: We use the "offline mode" of sqlx with [`sqlx prepare`](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/tree/main/sqlx-cli#enable-building-in-offline-mode-with-query) command from `sqlx-cli`

**1. Enable Offline Mode**

First, you need to enable the sqlx `offline` feature in the `Cargo.toml` related to the crate using macros such as `query!` or `query_as!`

```ini
[dependencies]
# ...
sqlx = { version = "0.6.3", features = ["macros", "offline", ...] }
```

**2. Generate Sqlx Metadata**

Then, you need to generate sqlx metadata:

```bash
cargo sqlx prepare # run 'cargo sqlx prepare --merged' in a cargo workspace
```

This command will generate a `sqlx-data.json` that will be used for the next build in sqlx offline mode.

**3. Build in Offline Mode**

In your `Dockerfile`, add the following ARG to tell to sqlx to build in offline mode:

```yaml
# In your build context (after the FROM instruction where you execute cargo build)
ARG SQLX_OFFLINE=true # You may also only declare it without value and set the value in your docker-compose file
```

Then, run `docker-compose build` to rebuild your image with above changes.

---

The drawback of this approach is that you have to update your `Dockerfile` to take into account the ARG `SQLX_OFFLINE`.

Also, be sure that the context used for build-time includes the `sqlx-data.json` file. You may need to also update the Dockerfile in order to copy the `sqlx-data.json` before to build your binary.

Comment: No spaces between SQLX_OFFLINE and = and true, btw

Answer (score 1):

While [the workaround posted by @Tenshock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75855909/4674154) does work, it does not really explain the problem.

While `Cannot assign requested address` seems to indicate missing permissions or something like that, that does not seem to be the case. Instead, the real root cause is that the link from `rust_backend` to `postgresdb` does exist only at runtime of `rust_backend` – during build of the image used for `rust_backend`, the service container can simply not see `postgresdb` (if `postgresdb` is even running – `depends_on` is also only adhered to for the resulting container, not the build service container, I believe). A similar problem is also handled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62015062/4674154) (`docker compose` specific) as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26551279/4674154) (more about general `docker build`, but also applicable here).

A nicer solution for this problem might be to run the service container that builds the image for `rust_backend` in host network mode. Normally, this can be done with `docker build --network host [...]`. Although documentation for doing this with `docker compose` is missing, [it can be done by adding `network: host` to the `build` key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47545276/4674154). Using this and modifying `DATABASE_URL` to adjust for host addressing, you get:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:

  postgresdb:
      container_name: postgresdb
      image: "postgres:13.3"
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234
        - POSTGRES_DB=rustdb
      volumes:
        - rust_api_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  rust_backend:
    container_name: rust_backend
    image: rust-api:1.0.0
    build: 
      context: .
      network: host
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:1234@localhost:5432/rustdb?sslmode=disable
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
  
  

volumes:
  rust_api_data: {}
```

While this solution solves the problem, it has the drawback that the build service container can not just access `postgresdb`, but also all other containers and services that are ordinarily only availible to the host. However, because I have trust that that building that container does not cause any malicious network traffic, I consider this risk acceptable – your security needs and risk assessment might be different, however (you can do some nasty stuff with procedural macros).