# Cannot connect to postgres container from rust container

Tags: postgresql, docker, rust, docker-compose, rust-sqlx

I am using [sqlx](https://crates.io/crates/sqlx)'s `query!()` macro which needs a connection to the database to check if the queries are correct at compile time. As you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75622804/error-communicating-with-database-cannot-assign-requested-address#answer-77145045) I added `network: host` to the build of my rust service

However, I cannot connect to the database once the container is up and running. Then I get `Io(Os { code: 111, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "Connection refused" })`. I don't understand why because the connection is working during compile time.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16.1
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .pg.env

  backend:
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      network: host
    env_file:
      - backend/.env
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

In the .env file from the backend there is just the DATABASE_URL variable.

Comment: What exactly do you have `DATABASE_URL` set to?  I would not expect to be able to connect to the database at all at compile time.  (What should happen if you delete and recreate the database, and then run the exact same compiled application, without rebuilding it?)

Comment: @david-maze The `DATABASE_URL` is `postgres://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres`. At compile time sqlx checks the sql queries that use the [macro](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/macro.query.html) for validity. That means the connection must be possible but it doesn't work once both containers are up and running.

Answer (score 0):

The `DATABASE_URL` tells your application where the database is located and how to connect to it. The `backend` service uses this URL to connect to the `postgres service`.

Whereas, `postgres` service serves as the PostgreSQL DATABASE SERVER for your application. This is where your application's data will be stored and managed. It's a separate, standalone service that your application (backend service) will connect to for all its data needs, like storing, retrieving, updating, and deleting data.

so for `postgres` service you should have 3 environment variables:

```
environment:
  - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  - POSTGRES_DB=name_of_db
```

for backend service you should have set `DATABASE_URL`

```
backend:
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres/name_of_db
```

Comment: That's exactly the setup I have but I cannot connect to the database from the backend

Comment: what command do u run to connect to the db

Comment: `let mut connection = PgConnection::connect(&database_url).await?;`
`connection.ping().await?;`

Comment: r u using rocket framework?